# when creating a folder or file in xcode, the first letter is always dark. how to fix this

Tags: xcode

[image]

i created a new folder.  but the N is dark , its so hard to see. anyone know how to fix this?

Comment: This is an Xcode bug, not much you can do about it.

Comment: Maybe using a light editor theme would help.

Comment: light mode on mac seems to be okay. it only has problems on dark mode